# response redirect in event handler

Tags: 2010, event-handlers

I try to redirect user after edit a list to another page in site. So I write this code at the end of my item_updated list handler

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.somewhere.com");
```

I pretty sure that this line of code is executed when I debug this handler but the page not redirect to page which I expect.

Is this the correct way to redirect page in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [SPUtility.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.redirect.aspx) method. See [this post](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/06/redirection-from-event-handler.html) for more details.

Comment: Post link is not working. MSDN link do not have any example. Can you provide some example or explain?

Comment: Post link is Spam. This answer should be edited/down-voted/removed