# Reload page From Event Receiver

Tags: event-receivers

How to reload a page from Event Receiver after adding item. I have an event receiver with following sample code, but after adding item, I would like reload a page, because my dropDown List should get added elements, and updated from this added item:

```
 public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemAdding(properties);

       if (properties.List.Title == "Wpisy")
       {
           SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Szczegoly"];

           // Stworzenie dwóch zmiennych typu data, jednej opisującej dzień Startowy, drugiej opisującej dzień końcowy
           DateTime dzienStart = new DateTime();
           DateTime dzienStop = new DateTime();

           // Podstawienie odpowiednich pól z propetisów pod wcześniej stworzone zmienne
           dzienStart = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.AfterProperties["DzienStart"]);
           // Zaistniała też potrzeba odjęcia dwóch godzin
           dzienStart = dzienStart.AddHours(-2.0);
           dzienStop = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.AfterProperties["DzienStop"]);
           dzienStop = dzienStop.AddHours(-2.0);

           // Uruchomienie pętli while, która to pętla będzie się wykonywać przez czas kiedy to zmienna dzienStart będzie mniejsza bądz równa zmiennej dzienStop
           while(dzienStart<=dzienStop){

               // Sprawdzenie Ifem, czy wybrane dni są równe sobocie, lub niedzieli
               if (dzienStart.DayOfWeek.ToString() ==  "Saturday" || dzienStart.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday")
               {
                   // Jeżeli zmienna ciągle inkrementowana dzienStart jest równa sobocie, lub niedzieli, to wwtedy następuje powiększenie dnia o jeden, zaś potem następuje kontynuacja pętli
                   dzienStart = dzienStart.AddDays(1.0);
                   continue;
               }
               // W przeciwnym wypadku następuje dodanie obiektu do listy
               else
               {              
                   SPListItem item = lstOtherList.Items.Add();
                   item["Kontrakt"] = properties.AfterProperties["Kontrakt1"];
                   item["Pracownik"] = properties.AfterProperties["Pracownik1"];
                   item["Dzien"] = dzienStart;
                   dzienStart = dzienStart.AddDays(1.0);
                   item.Update();
               }
           }

       } 

   }
   // Koniec ItemAdding
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grzegorz,

This question was previously asked in [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33033/response-redirect-in-event-handler)

Try to use [SPUtility.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.redirect.aspx) method. See [this post](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/06/redirection-from-event-handler.html) for more details.

Comment: Post link is not working. And MSDN link doesn't have example. The previous thread have same issue. can you explain in brief?